# Automatically convert pdf file to gif

Tags: typo3

In TYPO3 7.6 version i have made one extension in which i have one field to upload pdf, image. But when i upload PDF file it is automatically convert into gif format in backend.
so, is it possible to convert that file into jpg format?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to change the backend preview image format to `.jpg` or want to use that image in the frontend somewhere?

Comment: i also wanted to display that image into frontend for list all uploaded articles and click on detail. because of gif it is not easily readable.

Comment: I googled this http://www.netzkompetenz.ch/typo3/pdf-zum-bild-konvertierung-im-typo3-erstellt-pixliges-gif-mit-transparentem-hintergrund/ but I'm not sure if that's only for BE